# How can I synchronize some Flask-RESTful Resources?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have an Flask-RESTful API that acts as a gateway to TCP devices that cannot handle asynchronous calls to them.

Since for me `Resource` objects just spawn, I cannot queue and manage them from a single point of source.

I tried to create a decorator that `Resources` that need sync will use. In this decorator, I tried to append the id of TCP device (`load_id`) to a list in the global scope, and remove it after the request is handled.

The problem is, when an async request is made, the first `Resource` gets an empty list, appends to it, and while it is still being executed the second `Resource` is created for a second request. This second `Resource` instance also gets an empty list. Therefore I cannot actually make `Resource` instances share a list.

I tried this without a decorator, within `get`, `put` methods explicitly, with locks defined on database model objects or with a common handler object that manages locks on objects that are uniquely identified with `load_id`, but no avail, I always get a list that is outdated.

Here is the stripped down version of one:

```py
loads_with_query_in_progress = [] # Global scope
def disallow_async_calls(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        global loads_with_query_in_progress
        load_id = kwargs.get("load_id", None)
        load = Load.query.get(load_id)
        if load in loads_with_query_in_progress: # Load is in the list. Aborting.
            raise Exception
        else:
            loads_with_query_in_progress.append(load) # APPEND
            try:
                decorated_function_output = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                loads_with_query_in_progress.remove(load) # Expt handling cleanup
                raise e
            loads_with_query_in_progress.remove(load) # Remove lock
        return decorated_function_output
    return decorator

class LoadStateAPI(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required,
                  disallow_async_calls]
    ...
    def get(self, load_id):
        load = Load.query.get(load_id)
        try:
            rqObj = RelayQueryObject(load)
            rqObj.execute()
        except:
            raise
        if(rqObj.fsmState == CommState.COMPLETED):
            return {'state' : rqObj.response}, 200
```

Here on the code, in the first request the line commented with #APPEND changes the `loads_with_query_in_progress` in its scope. But when another request is spawned the variable `loads_with_query_in_progress` is fetched unedited.

Is there any way to resolve this async-sync conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy was due to the fact that production uses uwsgi, and uwsgi uses several processes, which results in phantom differences between shared objects, cause we were using different objects in different processes, but we were debugging with logging processes that all log to the same file.